# Database using an invalid character set(non-UTF8)

Tags: sql, linux, oracle

Sudden issue is seen when connecting to my database which has thrown me

```
[root@dub-mgrfarm113 oracle]# spacewalk-setup external-oracle
* Setting up Oracle environment.
* Setting up database.
** Database: Setting up database connection for Oracle backend.
Global Database Name or SID (requires tnsnames.ora)? orcl
Username? ray
Password?
** Database: Testing database connection.
Database is using an invalid (non-UTF8) character set: (NLS_CHARACTERSET = WE8MSWIN1252)
```

Is there a file or command I need?

Comment: [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm) in the Oracle docs.

Answer (score 0):

If spacewalk requires a UTF8 db, then you have to either recreate your DB and choose UTF8 as the characterset, or modify the existing db's charset (look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011) for the doc, or google 'oracle modify characterset' for blogs on how to do it).